# App center does not open .deb packages

Tags: package-management, software-center, deb, 23.10

As you can see, the bug is in the title. When I open a `.deb` package, the App Center shows a loading icon:

[image: Loading bug]

I have left it loading like this for more than two hours, but it continued spinning.

Is this a bug in Ubuntu, or a something with the app center on my computer? Any suggestions on what I can do to fix this?

Maybe some other application that will manage apps?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2023/10/install-deb-ubuntu-23-10-no-app-error

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The new Ubuntu App Center does not currently have the capability to install local .deb files. There is an [issue](https://github.com/ubuntu/app-center/issues/1407) open about this, and the functionality may eventually be added. In the meanwhile, you can use apt in the terminal to install the .deb

```
sudo apt install /path/to/package.deb
```

Or you can install a graphical .deb installer like `gdebi`.

Comment: Just to add to this answer. I believe the functionality has been fixed in either the beta or candidate channel for the snap-store.