# Issue with App Centre Loading Infinitely when Opening Debian Package

Tags: software-center

I hope this post finds you well. I am currently experiencing an issue with the App Centre application on Ubuntu, and I'm seeking assistance from the knowledgeable members of this forum.

Problem Description:
Whenever I try to open a Debian package using the App Centre application, the software window keeps loading indefinitely without any progress. This prevents me from installing or managing Debian packages effectively.

System Information:

Operating System: Ubuntu 23.10
App Centre Version: 45.0-1ubuntu1[image]
Additional Notes:
I would appreciate any guidance or suggestions from the community to resolve this issue. If anyone has encountered a similar problem or has insights into potential solutions, please share your experiences.

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Best regards, Ronak Kunwar

Comment: Does this answer your question? [New app center does not load .deb packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1501750/new-app-center-does-not-load-deb-packages)

Comment: Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting . Take the [tour].